# SQLPackage failing to login on azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, pipeline, sql-server-express, sqlpackage

Lately (since around 15/02/2024) in around half of the pipeline runs the SQLPackage executable fails to fully connect to the mssqllocaldb server that is started in a previous step. The main error is "No process is on the other end of the pipe".

I am not sure why this started happening or how to prevent it from happening, I also tried connecting with `Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;` without any success;

My solution consists of an SQL Server Database Project and an integration test project (among other things).

The database project has the following after build event:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <SQLDeployWorkingDirectory Condition="Exists('C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin\')">C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin\</SQLDeployWorkingDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
<Exec
  Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'"
  WorkingDirectory="$(SQLDeployWorkingDirectory)"
  Command="SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish
    /SourceFile:&quot;$(SolutionDir)$(MSBuildProjectName)\$(OutputPath)$(MSBuildProjectName).dacpac&quot;
    /TargetConnectionString:&quot;Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=$(MSBuildProjectName).Test; Integrated Security=true;&quot;" />
```

This is the start of the pipeline configuration file:

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
# Start of versioning variables
  botUserName: 'Azure DevOps pipeline'
  botEmail: 'Azure.Devops@pipeline.com'
  rootBranchName: 'main'
  sourceBranch: $[replace(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', '')]
  prBranchName: $[replace(variables['system.pullRequest.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', '')]
  latestVersion: 'v0.1.1'
  needsVersioning: False
  disable.coverage.autogenerate: 'true'
# End of versioning variables

steps:

# Needed for versioning
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Install .NET Coverage Tool'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'dotnet tool install --global dotnet-coverage'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Start SQL server'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'sqllocaldb start mssqllocaldb'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Info SQL server'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'sqllocaldb info mssqllocaldb'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

These are the errors for the VSBuild@1 step:

> ##[error]*** A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider(0,0): Error : 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

> ##[error]Project\Project.sqlproj(190,5): Error MSB3073: The command "SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"D:\a\1\s\Project\bin\Release\Project" /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=Project.Test; Integrated Security=true;"" exited with code -1.

> ##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.

There are seemingly no differences between the "Info SQL Server" steps of a failed and a successful run, example log:

```
Name:               mssqllocaldb
Version:            15.0.4153.1
Shared name:        
Owner:              fv-az902-225\VssAdministrator
Auto-create:        Yes
State:              Running
Last start time:    2/20/2024 9:30:53 AM
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#E9389DB3\tsql\query
```

Pipeline partial log for VSBuild@1

```
AfterBuild:
  SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"D:\a\1\s\Project\bin\Release\Project" /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=Project.Test; Integrated Security=true;"
  Publishing to database 'Project.Test' on server '(localdb)\mssqllocaldb'.
  Initializing deployment (Start)
##[error]*** A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider(0,0): Error : 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)
*** A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider : Named Pipes Provider, error : 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) [D:\a\1\s\Project\Project.sqlproj]
  Initializing deployment (Complete)
  Analyzing deployment plan (Start)
  Analyzing deployment plan (Complete)
  Updating database (Start)
  Creating database Project.Test...
  Creating Table [dbo].[Table]...
...
 Creating Procedure [dbo].[Procedure]...
  Update complete.
  Updating database (Complete)
  Successfully published database.
  Changes to connection setting default values were incorporated in a recent release.  More information is available at https://aka.ms/dacfx-connection
  Time elapsed 0:01:08.07
##[error]Project\Project.sqlproj(190,5): Error MSB3073: The command "SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"D:\a\1\s\Project\bin\Release\Project.dacpac" /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=Project.Test; Integrated Security=true;"" exited with code -1.
```

Comment: SQL Server typically isn't available to accept connections instantly: it takes time to mount all system database and user database files, rollback any pending transactions and/or upgrade files to the latest engine versions. For a regular instance I'd recommend tailing its `ERRORLOG` file for the line `SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required` but I don't know where you'd find that file for LocalDb instances.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I updated the answer to include the relevant part of VSBuild@1, the weird part is that it fails to connect and then it actually deploys the database, and after that it throws the second error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the YAML you posted, you are running the pipeline job on the Microsoft-hosted agents and try to connect to the automatic instance of LocalDB.

[The first time a user on a computer tries to connect to LocalDB, the automatic instance must be both created and started.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16#start-localdb-and-connect-to-localdb) You might need a few moments to wait for the instance to be created and started.

[image]

[Each time you run a pipeline on Microsoft-hosted agents, you get a fresh virtual machine for each job in the pipeline.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) So, each time when you try to connect to the automatic instance of LocalDB on Microsoft-hosted agents, it is your first time on the VM to try the connection.

---

For your case, you can try the following methods to see whether the issue can be fixed:

1. After the **`PowerShell@2`** task to run '**`sqllocaldb start mssqllocaldb`**' command and before the **`VSBuild@1`** task, add a step to run the sleep command for a few moments.

   ```yaml
   - task: PowerShell@2
     displayName: 'Info SQL server'
     inputs:
       targetType: 'inline'
       script: |
         sqllocaldb info mssqllocaldb
         Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
   ```
2. Set the "Number of retries if task failed" on the **`VSBuild@1`** task.

   ```yaml
   - task: VSBuild@1
     inputs:
       solution: '$(solution)'
       msbuildArgs: 'xxxx'
       platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
       configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
     retryCountOnTaskFailure: 5
   ```

---

Comment: But I already have a Task that runs `sqllocaldb info mssqllocaldb` right after `sqllocaldb start mssqllocaldb`, if it states that the instance is "running", doesn't that mean  it's ready to connect to?

Comment: The second approach seems to work (or the pipeline just doesn't feel like crashing anymore), I'll try it for a few more runs to see if it has definitively fixed the problem and I'll accept then, although 5 runs seems excessive, I'm trying out 3 for now. Thanks for all the help!